# Sendgrid batch emails php

Tags: php, swiftmailer, sendgrid

I'm attempting to use the Sendgrid SMTP API (4.0) with Swiftmailer (5.4) to send mass password reset links to users that have been imported into a new site .

The code below works, but every recipient can see the full list emails as they are all in the To: field. 
How can I send multiple emails at once using templates and substitutions without all email addresses being visible to each recipient. The BCC filter appears to take only one email.

```
<?php

$links = array('reset link 1', 'reset link 2');
$emails = array( 'example1@gmail.com', 'example2@gmail.com' );

$transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance( 'smtp.sendgrid.net', 587 );
$transport->setUsername( 'username' );
$transport->setPassword( 'password' );

$mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance( $transport );

$message = new \Swift_Message();
$response = $mailer->send( $message );
$message->setTo( $emails );
$message->setFrom( 'info@newwebsite.ie' );
$message->setBody( 'body content' );

$header = new Smtpapi\Header();
$header->addSubstitution( '%name%', $names );
$header->addSubstitution( '%source%', $sources );
$header->addSubstitution( '%link%', $links );

$filter = array(
  'templates' => array(
    'settings'  => array(
      'enable'          => 1,
      'template_id' => 'cc813g53-template-id'
    )
  )
);
$header->setFilters( $filter );
$message_headers = $message->getHeaders();
$message_headers->addTextHeader( HEADER::NAME,   $header->jsonString(JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) );

try {
    $response = $mailer->send( $message );
    print_r( $response ); //2 emails sent
} catch(\Swift_TransportException $e) {
    print_r('Bad username / password');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent recipients from seeing the full list of e-mails, you can loop each mail like this (untested code):

```
<?php
$emails = array( 'example1@gmail.com', 'example2@gmail.com' );

$transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance( 'smtp.sendgrid.net', 587 );
$transport->setUsername( 'username' );
$transport->setPassword( 'password' );
// You may need to move the mailer inside the foreach loop (untested).
$mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance( $transport );

foreach ($emails as $email) {
    $links = array('reset link 1', 'reset link 2');

    $message = new \Swift_Message();
    $response = $mailer->send( $message );
    $message->setTo( $email );
    $message->setFrom( 'info@newwebsite.ie' );
    $message->setBody( 'body content' );

    $header = new Smtpapi\Header();
    $header->addSubstitution( '%name%', $names );
    $header->addSubstitution( '%source%', $sources );
    $header->addSubstitution( '%link%', $links );

    $filter = array(
      'templates' => array(
        'settings'  => array(
          'enable'          => 1,
          'template_id' => 'cc813g53-template-id'
        )
      )
    );
    $header->setFilters( $filter );
    $message_headers = $message->getHeaders();
    $message_headers->addTextHeader( HEADER::NAME,   $header->jsonString(JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) );

    try {
        $response = $mailer->send( $message );
        print_r( $response ); //2 emails sent
    } catch(\Swift_TransportException $e) {
        print_r('Bad username / password');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, is it necessary to create a new SwiftMailer object for every email?